# Expand citations in latex with bibtex

Tags: bibtex, citing

I am writing a paper like the following one, and bibtex creates cites inside of cites:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

cite1~\cite{abc:oopsla2005} 
cite2~\cite{martinAl:oopsla2005}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{bib,crossref}

\end{document}
```

Where bib.bib contains:

```
@InProceedings{martinAl:oopsla2005,
author = {Michael Martin and Benjamin Livshits and Monica S. Lam},
title = {Finding application errors and security flaws using {PQL}: a program query language},
crossref = {oopsla2005},
pages = {365--383},
}
```

and crossref.bib contains:

```
@proceedings{oopsla2005,
key = {OOPSLA 2005},
booktitle =  {Proceedings of the 20th {ACM SIGPLAN} Conference on Object-Oriented Programming Systems, Languages and Applications (OOPSLA 2005)},
title =      {Proceedings of the 20th {ACM SIGPLAN} Conference on Object-Oriented Programming Systems, Languages and Applications (OOPSLA 2005)},
year =      2005,
address =      {San Diego, California, USA},
month =        oct,
publisher =     acm,
note =         sigplan # {, 40(11)}       
}
```

So, when I create the pdf file, I get:

> [1] M. Martin, B. Livshits, M. S. Lam, Finding application errors and security flaws using PQL: a program query language, in: [3], pp. 365–383. ACM SIGPLAN Notices, 40(11).
>
> [2] C. Allan, P. Avgustinov, A. S. Christensen, L. Hendren, S. Kuzins, O. Lhot ́ak, O. de Moor, D. Sereni, G. Sittampalam, J. Tibble, Adding trace matching with free variables to AspectJ, in: [3], pp. 345–364. ACM SIGPLAN Notices, 40(11).

where [3] is:

> [3] OOPSLA 2005, Proceedings of the 20th ACM SIGPLAN Conference on Object-Oriented Programming Systems, Languages and Applications (OOPSLA 2005), ACM Press, San Diego, California, USA, 2005. ACM SIGPLAN Notices, 40(11).

I would like to extend cites 1 and 2 to show the full content of these references. If I can show full references, I expect Latex/Bibtex removes reference 3.

Is it possible to set some parameters in Latex to achieve my goal? (I cannot use a line command option because my Latex file is compiled in the journal server)

In other words, I just want to get:

> [1] M. Martin, B. Livshits, M. S. Lam, Finding application errors and security flaws using PQL: a program query language, in Proceedings of the 20th ACM SIGPLAN Conference on Object-Oriented Programming Systems, Languages and Applications (OOPSLA 2005), ACM Press, San Diego, California, USA, 2005. ACM SIGPLAN Notices, 40(11).
>
> [2] C. Allan, P. Avgustinov, A. S. Christensen, L. Hendren, S. Kuzins, O. Lhot ́ak, O. de Moor, D. Sereni, G. Sittampalam, J. Tibble, Adding trace matching with free variables to AspectJ, in Proceedings of the 20th ACM SIGPLAN Conference on Object-Oriented Programming Systems, Languages and Applications (OOPSLA 2005), ACM Press, San Diego, California, USA, 2005. ACM SIGPLAN Notices, 40(11).

Comment: You should probably be compiling with something like `bibtex -min-crossrefs=5`.  However, your example above is missing the first citation, could you update the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your posting is missing a few details, such as an entry for the piece by Allan et al. My answer thus can't fully replicate what you're after. Some observations:

- To use BibTeX's `crossref` facility, use the `label` of one entry as the value of the `crossref` field of the other; don't use a field called `key`.
- You're already doing this, but just for completeness: The entry being cross-referenced must come later in the bib file (or bib files) than the entry (or entries) that contain a crossref to that entry.
- If you only want the "main" entries to show up in the bibliography but not the entry containing some of the crossref information, *don't* `\cite` the entry being cross-referenced.
- If you want abbreviated first names, you should use a bibliography style such as `abbrvnat` (if you use the `natbib` package) or `abbrv`; don't use `plain` (or `plainnat`).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{bib.bib}
@InProceedings{martinAl:oopsla2005,
crossref = {oopsla2005},
author = {Michael Martin and Benjamin Livshits and Monica S. Lam},
title = {Finding application errors and security flaws using {PQL}: a program query language},
pages = {365--383},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{crossref.bib}
@book{oopsla2005,
booktitle =  {Proceedings of the 20th {ACM SIGPLAN} Conference on Object-Oriented Programming Systems, Languages and Applications (OOPSLA 2005)},
title =      {Proceedings of the 20th {ACM SIGPLAN} Conference on Object-Oriented Programming Systems, Languages and Applications (OOPSLA 2005)},
year =      2005,
address =      {San Diego, California},
month =        oct,
publisher =     acm,
note =         sigplan # {, 40(11)}  ,     
}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}
%cite1~\cite{oopsla2005} %% no need to 

\cite{martinAl:oopsla2005}

\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
\bibliography{bib,crossref}
\end{document}
```